# Visual Studio 2010 indents the lines I modified making the whole code uggly as hell

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm working remotely on the Visual Studio 2010 of a friend and something begins to drive me crazy : Each time I modify a line, a yellow rectangle appears at the side and the line is indented making the code ugly as hell. Worst , If I try to re-indent correctly, the line is re-indented juste after, What can I do ?

[image]

Comment: 1. Don’t use VB.NET; 2. Fix your code. Visual Studio indents automatically according to blocks etc it detects.

Comment: @DanielB I can't use an another version for the moment. VS doesn't raise any errors at execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the settings, you can define the indentation level per block. The default is probably 4, and if you created your code somewhere else, and used a different amount (like 2) it won't match up. You should be able to change the settings to match what you prefer, and then the automatic indentation will be just fine.

The yellow bar tells you which lines were modified, and has nothing to do with the indentation settings. It will turn green when you save, and will be gone next time you open the file.